# How to remove stuck toilet hold down bolt

Tags: toilet, plumbing-fixture

I need to remove my toilet, but it appears that whoever installed it cut off or just sort of broke off the excess the hold-down bolt after they had installed the nut. When they did that they borked up the threads. When I try to remove the nut, the whole bolt just spins.

I have an angle grinder that I am thinking about using to just cut the nut off, but I am very worried about breaking the toilet itself.

Looking for other ideas to remove this nut.[image: close up of bolt and nut showing thread damage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower risk is to purchase a commercial nut splitter.

Link for reference; not endorsement.

[nut splitters on amzn](https://www.amazon.com/Nut-splitter/s?k=Nut%20splitter)

Slightly higher risk would be to position the angle grinder blade vertically and cut a slot in both the nut and the bolt. You can then hold the bolt with a slot screwdriver and turn the nut.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing and it worked. Slightly more difficult than I expected it to be - I basically had to cut the nut from three different angles before I could get it off.

Answer (score 1):

Use a small rotary tool (i.e. a "Dremel" Tool) with an abrasive cut-off wheel and cut the nut.

A larger angle grinder will probably do it if you are careful but it may be difficult to get it into the correct orientation.